# What type of module is this?

Tags: microcontroller, wifi, esp8266

[image]

It's likely ESP8266-01, but when I look better there a bit more differences at its components. Also I think its pinout is different with a ESP8266-01. When I attach it to PCB I made for ESP8266-01 it gets hotter and also there is no LED in that module to know its status.
Do you have an idea what this module is?

Thanks..

Comment: Can you retake the photo with the correct exposure for the board and crop it properly? It is not legible.

Comment: Looking at that photo is giving me vertigo, and a loss of ego...

Comment: Is that a through-hole HC49 together with 0603 passives? I wonder what the designer was thinking...

Comment: @Lundin - Can you explain? I am interested.

Comment: @Bort HC49 would be the name of the crystal package. For a long while these were the cheapest packages around. That's not really the case today though. Price aside, the disadvantage of HC49 is that they take quite a bit of board space, which seems to be somewhat critical here. In addition the package looks like through-hole since I see no pads, meaning it is even more space consuming (and suddenly expensive instead of cheap). The only reason that I can think of is that the manufacturer perhaps wants hobbyists with poor soldering skills to be able to change the crystal themselves.

Comment: @Lundin -  Oh, I thought 0603 was too small or large or something. Often the price of components in Asia don't follow the same trends as they do here. It's possible that there is a special business relationship going on, and/or the through-hole HC49's were overstock. Then again, I don't see a version of that module without it.

Comment: @Bort Nah through-hole components are always significantly more expensive, because of the assembly cost. And then they also have the through-hole socket strip mounted in the other direction, so these will very likely be soldered by hand. Thus: what were they thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have looks to be the **[nRF24L01](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01P)**. It's a wireless transceiver.

I must admit, that board looks a lot like a common ESP8266 module! Both are used for 2.4GHz wireless communication, and thus have similar PCB antennas. Both are about the same dimensions, and commonly have the same board color. Yikes!

nRF24L01:
[image: nRF24L01]

---

ESP8266:
[image: ESP8266]

Easy identification is as follows:
-The nRF24L01 board has a big, silver, oval-shaped crystal oscillator.
-The ESP8266 board has a smaller, flat, rectangle-shaped crystal oscillator. It also has a big FLASH chip right next to the main microchip.

There may *or may not* be silkscreen (printed label) differences, but that varies with all the clones out there, so I wouldn't count on those unless they are explicit.